# In Superset 1.1.0 - Restrict access to virtual datasets?

Tags: apache-superset

In superSet 1.1.0 I have two identical roles: Gamma and Gamma_2 with the same permissions.

User A belongs to Gamma

User B belongs to Gamma_2

User A creates a virtual dataset based on the query. Currently, user B can list and access such virtual dataset.

Which permission should I remove from Gamma_2 so user B cannot access the virtual dataset created by A?